# ERROR: Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length"

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to upload a file to document library using below code.

```
function uploadDocument(buffer, fileName) {
            ohrIDFolder = $("#ohrID").val();
            var actualFolder = "EFMSEmployeeDocumentList" + "/" + topFolder;
            var url = String.format(
                "{0}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" +actualFolder+"')/Files/Add(url='{1}', overwrite=true)",
                _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, fileName);

            var call = jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: buffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                        "Content-Length": buffer.byteLength
                    }
                });

            return call;
    }
```

So I am getting this error `Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length"`.

What should I do to solve this error?

Comment: The snippet above seems to be very similar to the API example from [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery#code-example-1-upload-a-file-across-sharepoint-domains-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `"Content-Length": buffer.byteLength` from your code, it will be set automatically when the browser executes the call.

[More information in answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210507/ajax-post-error-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-connection)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [standard][1] says it must:

For security reasons, these steps should be terminated if header is [...]

- Connection
- Content-Length

Messing around with those could expose various request smuggling attacks, so the browser always uses its own values. There's no need or reason to try to set the request length, as the browser can do that accurately from the length of data you pass.